# lsusb is taking forever

Tags: 18.04, lsusb

I might have done some stupid things while trying to install a network driver. Now when I run lsusb, it doesn't return any output. The command just keeps executing indefinitely. I can still kill it with CTRL-C or CTRL-Z. Is there a way I can fix this? If this indicates a more serious issue, how  do I address that?

Comment: This can sometimes happen if a USB device is refusing to be queried for whatever reason. The first thing to do would be to disconnect all external USB devices from the machine and try `lsusb` again. If it continues to hang, then a driver for an internal device (such as a keyboard or touchpad) may be corrupted and in need of repair. System logs in `/var/log/syslog` may contain information relating to the issue.

Comment: Disconnecting devices didn't help, it appears to be a problem with an internal device

Comment: Cool. So you've narrowed it down to an internal device. This is progress. Does any log file show what might be causing the issue?

Comment: I tried to run the command again and checked the syslog file. It doesn't display anything after opening the terminal. I also checked other logfiles in the directory, but I couldn't spot anything meaningful

Comment: You had mentioned that this started after trying to install a network driver. Can you uninstall the driver? What does `sudo lshw -C network` reveal? If the network device is on the USB bus, it could be interfering with the rest of the system.

Comment: This command produces a similar issue to the one in question. However, this one does not respond to CTRL-C or CTRL-Z. I don't know how to remove the broken driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the broken network driver and rebooting.